# Css make tabs vertical if has been overflowed

Tags: html, css

I have horizontal tabs 1 as,

[image: img1]

How can I make tabs vertical on window resize than it has been overflowed?
like this:

[image: img2]

I don't want usign @media because tabs are dinamic and may be only 1-2 tabs and it will display good in horizontal view

Comment: java-script is probably the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JS/jQuery to calculate total width of tabs and check if it's grater than container width.

```
var totalWidth = 0;
var availableWidth = $('.tabs-container').width();

$('.tabs').each(function () {
    totalWidth += $(this).outerWidth(true);
});

$('.tabs-container')
    .toggleClass('v-tabs', totalWidth >= availableWidth)
    .toggleClass('h-tabs', totalWidth < availableWidth);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Jquery to add a new class on a window resize

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
    $("tabs").addClass("nice looking class");
     }
```

other than this i would use a responsive grid.

Comment: It will always add classes, no matter of tabs overflow

Answer (score 0):

Basically join Justinas and Troajans answers together:

```
function checkTabWidths(){
      var totalWidth = 0;
      var availableWidth = $('.tabs-container').width();
      $('.tabs-container').removeClass('v-tabs h-tabs');
      $('.tabs').each(function () {
          totalWidth += $(this).outerWidth(true);
      });
      if (totalWidth >= availableWidth) {
          $('.tabs-container').addClass('v-tabs');
      } else {
          $('.tabs-container').addClass('h-tabs');              
      }

}
 $( window ).resize(function() {
    checkTabWidths(); // Check widths on resize
 }
checkTabWidths(); // To check on load
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to do that:

```
//first get the container width
var container=$("#containID").width();
//then get the total width of each tabs
var totalWidthOfTabs=0;
$("#containID .tabs").each(function(){
    totalWidthOfTabs+=$(this).width();
});
//when window resize, do something
$( window ).resize( function(){
     if(totalWidthOfTabs>container){
         $("#containID .tabs").css("width","100%");
     }
});
```

just an idea to do what you want. I do not check it whether it is correct or not, you can change it if the example is wrong~